# Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable (in array multidimensional)

Tags: php, arrays, count, warnings

I'm trying to count all the records of a multidimensional array with this method:

```
$totals=intval(array_sum(array_map("count",$array_name[$id])));
```

But it gives me the following error:

```
Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
```

I read that it is due to php 7.2, and in fact I just made the migration from version 5, however, given the particular syntax, I could not solve with a isset() or an is_array().
Can someone help me to solve this problem?
If exist a better way to make this count, is ok for me :)
Thanks in advance
Hello

Comment: Don't you think we need more information to help you. Like the array perhaps? And what $id is

Answer (score -1):

Pass in an anonymous function that checks:

```
$totals=intval(
  array_sum(
    array_map(
      function($a){
        if( is_countable($a) ) { return count($a); }
        else { return 1; }
      },
      $array_name[$id]
    )
  )
);
```